# How can I have a index.html page that has all the head tags for all the other html pages so I prevent dubble code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let say I usee app.js or a bootstrap cdm link for all my html pages but I dont want to add it to every single page. How can I make a index.html that includes it so all the other html pages first loads the index.html head and then its own head.
I use javascript for my project.

I tried to search it upp but none of the questions were the same as mine. My school project used this method so I thought this was a good idea but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: That's not a good idea. If you know PHP it'd be better off to use PHP to generate the pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an html file that will house the links you want to keep introducing in subsequent pages such as a head.html file for example, then inside it place the links and other content you deem necessary to be in the head, for example I can place the charset and viewport meta tags and the CDN link for Bootstrap.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then in your subsequent pages that you want to include these links in their respective head elements, you can place a script tag within their head tags or at the end of your content within the body tags with this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    try {
         const response = await fetch("head.html");
         const headContent = await fetch("head.html").text();
         const headElement = document.querySelector("head");

         headElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", headContent);
    } 
    catch(error) {
         console.log("Error fetching head.html", error);
    }
});
```

You can also put the code within its own JavaScript file then link that file within the pages you need if you want to avoid having the code plainly written within your HTML file.

Now every page that uses this will contain the